# react component is no updateing the view after deleting an item

Tags: reactjs

this the onDelete function which supposed to update the state and the item should disappear from the list once the delete button is pressed

```js
onDelete = async (id) => {
        const messages = await Api.deleteMessage(id);
        const messageId = id;
        const filterdMessages =this.state.messages.filter((message) => {
            return message.id !== messageId
        });
        this.setState({
            messages: [...filterdMessages]
        });   
    }
```

and this what is being rendered

```js
render() {
        const {
            messages
        } = this.state;

        const $messages = messages.map((message) => <MessageItem onDelete={this.onDelete} key={message.id} {...message} />);

        console.log( $messages);
        return (

            <section className="messages">
                <ul>
                    {$messages}
                </ul>
            </section>
        )
    }
```

this the messageItem

```js
export default ({ id, body, onResolve, onDelete, license_plate }) => {

    const onResolveClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        onResolve(id);
    };

    const onDeleteClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        onDelete(id);
    };

    return (
        <li className="MessageItem">
            <span> <b>{license_plate} </b>{body}</span>
            <button onClick={onDeleteClick}>Delete</button>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code? you are not give enough information to understand what is going on…

Comment: you misspelled `onDelete` when defining the function, you wrote: `nDelete`

Comment: sorry i misspelled it here not in the actual code

Comment: Try adding a sandbox example https://codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1):

You are using the key as `key={message._id}` but filtering by `message.id`.

```
// v Always undefined, the expression always false.
message.id !== messageId
```

```
const filterdMessages = this.state.messages.filter(message => {
//       v message.id
  return message._id !== messageId;
});
```

Comment: the id inside message is id not _id, however i fixed it but still not working

Comment: Try showing the whole producible code, how you call `props.onDelete` in `MessageItem`

Answer (score 0):

Should be `onDelete={() => this.onDelete(message._id)}`

Comment: this would invoke the function immediatly and ruined everything

Comment: Nope, `onDelete={this.onDelete(message._id)}`, would invoke the function, in most implementations.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code

1) You are not passing the `ID` in argument

2) You are using `_id` instead of `id` for `key` prop

```js
_onDelete = async (id) => {
  await Api.deleteMessage(id);
  const { messages } = this.state;
  const filterdMessages = messages.filter((message) => message.id !== messageId);

  this.setState({ messages: [...filterdMessages]});   
}   

render() {
  const { messages } = this.state;

  return (
    <section className="messages">
      <ul>
          {
            messages.map(message => (
              <MessageItem
                onDelete={() => this._onDelete(message.id)}
                key={message.id}
                {...message}
              />
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: when I used your code it says  Parsing error: Identifier 'messages' has already been declared

Comment: still the same it update only if i refresh the page

Comment: Can you create a demo link? I need to run it to find the root cause.